# Android login register sql (phpmyadmin)

Tags: android, database, eclipse

I am new to data base connecting.

I want to develop a login/register application that is connected to an external online database. Can you help me plz.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer these links,

[php mysql database connectivity android tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0_XE0UFeWvaY5NeFcFaGmEFJmJGhnims)

[androidhive tutorial about connecting mysql database with android app](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Comment: Thank you for the replay actually i need some thing for register/login for a remote data base that is hosted online not locally